# Java convert letter to number in 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, integer

I have an array: `[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]`

Array value such as `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` must be converted to number (integer).

Let's say, `a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, ..., f = 5`.

So, the result of converting should be: `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]`

How to do that in Java?

Comment: Is not very clear. Can you show the code you have?

Comment: Ahem... traverse the arrays and use Integer.parse(String) on their elements?

Answer (score 1):

Characters are sequential (and stored as numbers) - so basically, you're looking for the difference between the given character and `'a'`:

```
char[][] chars = /* fill the array */;

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < chars[i].length; ++k) {
        // To produce an int value (e.g., replace 'a' with 0):
        chars[i][j] -= 'a'; 

        // If you want a printable char (e.g., replace 'a' with '0')
        // comment out the above statement and use this one instead:
        // chars[i][j] = chars[i][j] - 'a' + '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for `0` (int literal) not `'0'`. However I amend my answer to include both options, for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII / Decimal value of 'a' is 97. 
I consider that you have array of characters.

Typecasting any character to integer return its decimal/ascii value.

```
char ch = 'a'; //define character
int ch_ascii = (int)ch; // get its ascii/decimal value
System.out.println(ch_acii); //Ascii of 'a' = 97
```

You will get 97 as output.

So iterate through your 2-d array.

Typecast character to integer and subtract 97 to it.
You will get the output in the way you want.

Hope this helps.
Comment if further help is required.

Answer (score 1):

use ASCII value, and then take their round off e.g a to z 97 to 122 subtract with sentinel value 97 and you will get your results

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String[][] test = {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}};
    for (int i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
        for (int o=0; o<test[i].length; o++) {
            Log.d("AWAISKING_OLD", "--------------");
            Log.d("AWAISKING_OLD", ""+test[i][o]);
            test[i][o] = test[i][o].replace("a", "1");
            test[i][o] = test[i][o].replace("b", "2");
            test[i][o] = test[i][o].replace("c", "3");
            test[i][o] = test[i][o].replace("d", "4");
            Log.d("AWAISKING_NEW", ""+test[i][o]);
            Log.d("AWAISKING_OLD", "--------------");
        }
    }
```